# Q: Prove 1+1/2+1/3+...+1/(n-1) = lnn+c+o(n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, fractions

Is there a way to prove 
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac {1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n-1} = \ln(n)+c+o(n)$$ where c is a constant? Any idea will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Taylor's Series?

Comment: Use e.g. the Euler-MacLaurin formula:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula (look also for *Examples*)